# Alternative to 'Tab' for external keyboard hyperlink selection/navigation?

Tags: browser, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hyperlinks

On Chrome for Windows using Ctrl-F to search for link text and then Ctrl-Enter (or Esc then Enter) to open the link is a method. But it doesn't appear to work on the mobile version (on my Nexus 7 with USB keyboard, at least).

Has anyone had this work, or found an alternative method? Or another browser (perhaps uzbl-like) that is decent for keyboard-only browsing? Or an extension for Firefox Mobile? I am having no luck in any of these directions and endless Tabbing is getting me down.